VXLAN over Wireguard tunnel
I have two hosts in separate ip networks that are connected via Wireguard. Both these hosts reach each other via ping 
1st host Wireguard ip: 10.8.0.2 
2nd host Wireguard ip: 10.8.0.4
I want to setup a vxlan overlay via this Wireguard setup. For this, I have added VXLAN setup commands into the wg0.conf file on both hosts
On 10.8.0.2 (vxlan ip: 10.8.1.2)
PostUp = ip link add name bridge0 type bridge
PostUp = ip link set bridge0 up
PostUp = ip link add vxlan0 type vxlan id 42 local  10.8.0.2 remote 10.8.0.4 dev wg0 dstport 4789
PostUp = ip addr add 10.8.1.2/24 dev vxlan0
PostUp = ip link set vxlan0 up
PostUp = ip link set vxlan0 master bridge0
PostDown = ip link set vxlan0 nomaster
PostDown = ip link delete vxlan0
PostDown = ip link delete bridge0 

On 10.8.0.4 (vxlan ip: 10.8.1.4)
PostUp = ip link add name bridge0 type bridge
PostUp = ip link set bridge0 up
PostUp = ip link add vxlan0 type vxlan id 42 local 10.8.0.4 remote 10.8.0.2 dev wg0 dstport 4789
PostUp = ip addr add 10.8.1.4/24 dev vxlan0
PostUp = ip link set vxlan0 up
PostUp = ip link set vxlan0 master bridge0
PostDown = ip link set vxlan0 nomaster
PostDown = ip link delete vxlan0
PostDown = ip link delete bridge0

On both hosts net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
On 10.8.0.4 
When I ping 10.8.1.2 , it's giving error
ping 10.8.1.2
PING 10.8.1.2 (10.8.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.1.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.8.1.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.8.1.4 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.8.1.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4073ms
pipe 4

Tcpdump shows the requests
sudo tcpdump -i vxlan0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on vxlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:44:01.236081 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.2 tell 10.8.1.4, length 28
11:44:02.255832 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.2 tell 10.8.1.4, length 28
11:44:03.279999 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.2 tell 10.8.1.4, length 28
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

EDIT:
brctl show bridge0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
bridge0         8000.12cd00736e5c       no              vxlan0

On 10.8.0.2 
ping 10.8.1.4 doesn't work either but interestingly, there are requests and responses as well
ping 10.8.1.4
PING 10.8.1.4 (10.8.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.8.1.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2077ms

sudo tcpdump -i vxlan0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on vxlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
15:16:33.461571 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.4 tell XPS-13-9360, length 28
15:16:33.512632 ARP, Reply 10.8.1.4 is-at 12:cd:00:73:6e:5c (oui Unknown), length 28
15:16:34.513291 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.4 tell XPS-13-9360, length 28
15:16:34.805377 ARP, Reply 10.8.1.4 is-at 12:cd:00:73:6e:5c (oui Unknown), length 28
15:16:35.538017 ARP, Request who-has 10.8.1.4 tell XPS-13-9360, length 28
15:16:35.829203 ARP, Reply 10.8.1.4 is-at 12:cd:00:73:6e:5c (oui Unknown), length 28
15:16:49.346396 IP6 fe80::10cd:ff:fe73:6e5c > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
^C
7 packets captured
7 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel 

EDIT:
brctl show bridge0
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
bridge0     8000.faa20a14f62a   no      vxlan0

My final goal is to be able to reach layer 2 devices in both networks from these hosts.

Do a tcpdump on the WireGuard interfaces, please. Make sure 1) the VXLAN tunnel is trying to send encapsulated packets over wg0 as it should, and 2) the WireGuard tunnel works for other things. Is 10.8.0.4 able to ping 10.8.0.2? And most importantly, are any IP addresses assigned to the bridge0 interface?

Wireguard tunnel works for other things. Both 10.8.0.2 and 4 are able to ping each other. Only vxlan0 is present on the bridge0 interface. No other ip addresses. VXLAN tunnel is sending encapsulated packets over wg0

Okay, but you show the IP addresses being added to vxlan0, and then vxlan0 being bridged. That in itself doesn't seem right on Linux – interfaces that are bridged only act as L2 ports and don't process IP. Does the same problem happen if you add the IP address to bridge0 instead?

adding the ip adderesses to the bridge0 instead of vxlan0 interface worked. Thank you. Now, I want to be able to reach layer 2 devices in both networks from these hosts. How can I do that?
